# Ignoring field types in Python list returned by arcpy.ListFields()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, fields-attributes, data-management

I am generally just wondering if there is a nice and easy way in python to ignore all fields of a specifiy type (eg string) in a feature class.

At the moment I am doing it with

```
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass)]
field_names = field_names[19:len(field_names)-2]
```

which ignores the first 19 and last 2 fields of my FC which are all string-fields but it would be better for me to have a code which just generally ignores all fields of a specific type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a full list and then remove the ones you don't want:

```
AllFields      = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass)]
StringFields   = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass,field_type='String')]
NoStringFields = [x for x in AllFields if x not in StringFields ]
```

Which could be compressed onto a single line:

```
NoStringFields = [x for x in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass)] if x not in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass,field_type='String')]]
```

However, this will leave you with OID fields, shape fields, rasters, GUIDs...  probably, for generality, it would be safer to build up by field type:

```
InterestFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass,field_type='Single')]
InterestFields.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass,field_type='Double')])
InterestFields.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass,field_type='Integer')])
InterestFields.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass,field_type='SmallInteger')])
```

There is not 'anything that's a number' list for [ListFields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001p000000) but you can extend a list with a list (not append, that would add a list *in* the list..) for example:

```
list_A = ['a','b','c']
list_B = ['d','e','f']

list_A.extend(list_B)
List A now ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

list_A.append(list_B)
List A now ['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

To use this list in a cursor:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featureclass,InterestFields) as Scur:
    for Row in Scur:
        # now index the rows' fields by their index:
        print(str(Row[0])) # print what the first field value is.
```

it can get a little difficult generically indexing field names to field indices, you can use index to get the index of the field:

```
LookForField = "SomeField"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featureclass,InterestFields) as Scur:
    for Row in Scur:
        if LookForField in InterestFields: # True if LookForField is found in InterestFields
            print(str(Row[InterestFields.index(LookForField)]))
```

but watch your case sensitivity... "dog" != "Dog", so prepare for this by either using `f.name.lower()` or `f.name.upper()` to convert to lower or upper case respectively.

Comment: Thanks that was very useful and works excellent!
If I would add a python line just referencing to fields with a specific name would it be with SearchCursor? Like  **FieldsCursor = ["WID", "BID"] LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FCLASS,(FieldsCursor))])** or how would you do that? It doesn't work for me!

Comment: How you specify it makes a big difference. FieldsCursor = ["WID", "BID"]  is fine, arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FCLASS,FieldsCursor) works, but f.name is not in the cursor. I will put in an example of using a da cursor with limited fields..

Answer (score 2):

A complete one-liner would be

```
[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass) if f.type not in ["String"]]
```

You can add more entries to the latter list that you do not want to include, or the ones that you want to include by removing **not** operator.